# Asset Gallery to GatsbyImage (Gatsby v3+)

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I have an asset gallery in my DatoCMS (only images) and would like to display them via GatsbyImage (from the new gatsby-plugin-image). However, as there are several images and not always the same amount of them in my blog posts, I need to write a loop (I guess?) but don’t know how to.

My post component:

```
export default function ProjectContent(props) {
    return (
        <div className="projectContent">
            <div className="projectContent__assets">
                <GatsbyImage image={props.imageGallery} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the project template component:

```
export default function Project({ data }) {
    return (
        <>
            <ProjectContent 
                imageGallery={data.datoCmsProject.photos.gatsbyImageData}
            />
        </>
    )
}

    export const query = graphql`
    query($slug: String!)
      {
        datoCmsProject(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
          photos {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: CONSTRAINED)
          }
        }
    }`
```

At the moment, no image is shown. I’ve managed to get GatsbyImage + DatoCMS to work already with single images, but not with the asset gallery.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think are trying to do:

```
export default function Project({ data }) {

return (
    <>
        <ProjectContent 
            imageGallery={data.datoCmsProject.photos}
        />
    </>
 )
}

export const query = graphql`
query($slug: String!)
  {
    datoCmsProject(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      photos {
          gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: CONSTRAINED)
      }
    }
}`
```

Note that you are sending the full array of `photos` (`data.datoCmsProject.photos`) to the child component.

And in the child component:

```
export default function ProjectContent(props) {
    return (
        <div className="projectContent">
            <div className="projectContent__assets">
                {props.imageGallery.map(photo=>{
                   return <GatsbyImage image={photo.gatsbyImageData} />
               })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It's quite self-explanatory but in your case, `photos` (sent as `imageGallery` to the child component) is an array of images. Once you get it there (`props.imageGallery`) you only need to loop through them, as you said, and print them using the new `<GatsbyImage>` component. Each instance of the `photo` (the iterable variable) has the `gatsbyImageData` required.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear and fast response!!! Totally worked for me and with your comments everything makes sense! Much appreciated!